# How to give access to the script using role?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter and data table. I am displaying the list. Now what I am doing is, I have to display all the list to the `role id 1` and limited access on `role id 2`.

I tried in the controller which is working

```
if($this->session->userdata['login_session']['role']==1 ){ 
$action='<sel ect></select>';

}
else{
$action='';
}
```

**View**

This is also working.

```
<table id="emp-leadList">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<?php if($this->session->userdata['login_session']['role']==1 ){ ?><th>Action</th><?php }?>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

But I am getting the issue on the script. I want to know what code I have to use in the script

**JS**

```
$('#emp-leadList').DataTable( {
        language: {
        sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_",// remove entries text
        searchPlaceholder: "Search",
        emptyTable:     "No record found",
        search:""
      },
       "autoWidth": false,
        "ordering": false,// remove sorting effect from header 
        "processing": true,
        //"serverSide": true,
         "order":[],
        "scrollX": true,
        //"bInfo" : false,
        "pageLength": 25,
        "paging": true,
        //"deferRender": true,
        // "bDeferRender": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url" : baseUrl + "/Customer_control/emp_list",
            "type" : "POST"
             // "dataSrc": ""
        },
       "columns": [
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "action" }
            ],
           "columnDefs": [
            //{ width: '3%', targets: 0 },
            { width: '13%', targets: 0 },
            { width: '8%', targets: 1 }
        ]

    });
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: If role id is _not_ `1`, then the `action` column shouldn't come. Also have a server side validation for this.

Comment: @vivek_23, Yes right if role id is not 1 then action column  shouldn't come. I haven't use server side validation for this